# Is it possible to type two function array parameters such that the second parameter has length of one more than the first parameter?

Tags: typescript

function array parameters such that the second parameter has length of one more than the first parameter?

```
const func = (arr1: number[], arr2: number[]) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preamble: I'm not so advanced in TS (yet) but while this question lacks better answers see what I could end up with (I will drop as one of real masters participate and provide a more proper solution)

```
type plusone<T> =
    T extends 1 ? 2 :
    T extends 2 ? 3 :
    T extends 3 ? 4 : never;

type plusoneLength<T> = { length: plusone<T> };

function f<T>(left: { length: T }, right: plusoneLength<T>): void { }

f([1, 2] as const, [1, 2, 3] as const);
```

ts playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBGA2CuBnA9gOwgHgCoD4oF4AoKEqLKCAD2AlQBNEoBGKAfigCYoAuY08qjXqMu7AMw8+JAdVoMoE9gBYeUdADcIAJwDchQqEgwEKdABlaAc2AALbHnxQA3lFhXb3Y0jSZcUAL56hABm8KgAxsAAlmhQwfYAFG7BwJ4ubqjWNp7k-gA0UFpRljapXqYQFpm29gCUnurIUXTOAfrBCQDaTAUcALpQAIaM4WiIwAXdvQViA8NQo6jjtXpAA

Answer (score 0):

Yes... kind of.

```
declare function takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger<
    A extends unknown[] | readonly unknown[] & { length: Tail<B>['length']; },
    B extends (unknown[] | readonly unknown[])
>(a: A, b: B): void;

takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger(['baz'] as const, ['foo', 'bar'] as const); // OK
takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger([] as const, ['foo', 'bar'] as const, ); // Error
takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger(['baz', 42] as const, ['foo', 'bar'] as const); // Error
```

Note the `as const` used here: that’s because without those, both `A` and `B` will be inferred as type `string[]`. In other words,

```
takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger(['baz'], ['foo', 'bar']); // OK
takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger([], ['foo', 'bar']); // OK ← but shouldn’t be!
takesTupleAndTupleOnelonger(['baz', 42], ['foo', 'bar']); // OK ← but shouldn’t be!
```

Moreover, if you don’t have hard-coded arrays at all, and want to just check something like `a.length === b.length - 1`, there is no way of “saving” that result in the type domain so that it will be available to `takesTupleAndTupleOneLonger`—you’ll still be allowed because you’ll be dealing with arrays of unknown (to the compiler) length, but it won’t be safe the way you want.

Still, if dealing with known-at-compile-time arrays, this could be useful.

Finally, my implementation relied on `Tail`, which I have defined in an ambient `.d.ts` file like so:

```
/** Used internally for `Tail`. */
type AsFunctionWithArgsOf<T extends unknown[] | readonly unknown[]> = (...args: T) => any;

/** Used internally for `Tail` */
type TailArgs<T> = T extends (x: any, ...args: infer T) => any ? T : never;

/** Elements of an array after the first. */
type Tail<T extends unknown[] | readonly unknown[]> = TailArgs<AsFunctionWithArgsOf<T>>;
```